# How to get toastr to work in Typescript

Tags: typescript, toastr

I am converting a project over to Typescript.  I am having issues with toastr.

```
import {toastr} from "toastr";
```

I downloaded the typescript definition file with Nuget and included it in the project.

It has this export at the end of the file:

```
declare var toastr: Toastr;
declare module "toastr" {
export = toastr;
}
```

However, I get the compile time error: `Modle "toastr" has no exported member 'toastr'`

How to I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import * as toastr from "toastr";
```

Doing that will import the entire module as `toastr`.

Comment: In addition, adding @types/toastr adds the typescript typings! (npm install --save @types/toastr)

Comment: Shouldn't that be --save-dev instead?

Comment: This works. And then use it like `toastr.info('something')`